# Running VMC on Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, cloud-foundry

I've followed the simple instructions for installing VMC on Mountain Lion (`sudo gem install vmc`), but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ vmc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate multi_json (~> 1.4.0, runtime) for ["vmc-0.4.7"], already activated multi_json-1.5.0 for ["cfoundry-0.4.19", "vmc-0.4.7"] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/vmc:18
```

Can anyone help me with diagnosing this?  Is this an issue with the version of Ruby installed?  I don't really want to blindly jump through hoops to upgrade Ruby for this one thing. I tried installing an older version of multi-json with `gem install multi_json -v 1.4.0`, but this didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like vmc is picking `multi_json` (one of its dependencies) with version 1.5, which is not compatible with 1.4

What you can do is `sudo gem uninstall multi_json` and when prompted, answer to have version 1.5 removed.

Comment: Thanks ebottard, that sorted it

Comment: Another hint / good idea on OS X is to use rvm - the Ruby Version Manager - to install Ruby for your own user account, that means you won't have to use sudo to install gems system-wide. Glad Eric helped to resolve your issue.